# I can't get the cordova stepcounter plugin to work

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I wanted to develop a mobile app using Cordova and the [Cordova Step Counter Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-stepcounter). Everything went flawlessly with the install and initialisation of the step counter however I am not able to get the current amount of steps when using the corresponding function. Does anybody have an idea how to get the return of the getStepCount() function.
I tried:

```
success = function(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
failure = function() {
        alert("Error calling CordovaStepCounter Plugin");
}
stepcounter.start(startingOffset,success,failure);
var steps=stepcounter.getStepCount()
```

and:

```
success = function(message) {
        var steps=message;
        alert(message);
    }
    failure = function() {
        alert("Error calling CordovaStepCounter Plugin");
    }
stepcounter.start(startingOffset,success,failure);
stepcounter.getStepCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to stop the counter after you start it!

```
 stepcounter.stop(success, failure);
```

Then get the count

```
  stepcounter.getTodayStepCount(success, failure);
```

Or

```
  stepcounter.getStepCount(success, failure);
```